# How to use _Assertions object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, storage-access-framework, filewalker

I'm trying to recreate a file walker (like `File('/path').walk()`) for Android's Storage Access Framework. This is a snippet from the original `FileTreeWalk`:

```kotlin
private abstract class DirectoryState(rootDir: File) : WalkState(rootDir) {
    init {
        if (_Assertions.ENABLED)
            assert(rootDir.isDirectory) { "rootDir must be verified to be directory beforehand." }
    }
}
```

It seems that `_Assertions` is only visible inside its module (`internal` visibility), which seems to be the stdlib:

```
@PublishedApi
internal object _Assertions {
    @JvmField
    @PublishedApi
    internal val ENABLED: Boolean = javaClass.desiredAssertionStatus()
}
```

Is there a way that I can check `_Assertions.ENABLED` in my walker?

Comment: Why do you need to check it?  If it's not enabled, won't the assertion have no effect anyway?

Comment: @gidds Just for the sake of completion.